# Composer: "Content-length mismatch" & "http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded..."

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, doctrine, composer-php

When I try to create a new laravel project with "laravel new project"
I got this  error:

```
Content-Length mismatch
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
```

When I do "composer update" or "composer install doctrine/dbal", I got the error too.
And my composer is too slow.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe it is because you have not change you composer's url. I run this in my shell and it's work.  And i guess the url is different in different city. Hope it will help you guys.

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.phpcomposer.com
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this answer recommends a Chinese mirror of packagist. If you are in China, then this will probably speed things up for you, but if you are not, don't do it.

Answer (score 6):

I got this same error and solved it only changing the `http` protocol in composer repository config with `https`:

```
composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org
```

Answer (score 6):

clear the composer cache with the following command:

```
composer clear-cache
```

Answer (score 3):

I get this error when I'm in China. This is what works for me:

1. Turn on a Chinese VPN
2. Run `composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.phpcomposer.com`
3. Update your composer

Answer (score 2):

Just note useful information for this error:
This is a network error regarding ipv6. I can't know exactly what causes it. But we can fix it through a workaround solution

**Workaround Linux:**
Run command

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"
```

**Workaround Windows:**

On windows, the only way is to disable ipv6 entirely I am afraid (either in windows or in your home router).

**Workaround Mac OS X:**
Get the name of your network device:

```
$ networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

Disable IPv6 on that device (in this case "Wi-Fi"):

```
$ networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
```

Run Composer ...
You can enable IPv6 again with:

```
networksetup -setv6automatic Wi-Fi
```

That said, if this fixes your problem, please talk to your ISP about it to try to resolve the routing errors. That's the best way to get things resolved for everyone.

Refer to this article: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#operation-timed-out-ipv6-issues-

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is a rate limit on the repository per IP. Could it be, that you did a lot of requests in a short time? So just wait a few hours and try again. I had the same problem while trying to automate things with docker and ran the docker script several times.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried reinstall composer a lot of time.

Comment: After 10h without any request, I still get this error. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to your connection to the server

1.You should check your internet.
2.Use a VPN if possible.

3.Now try again to install the desired package.

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer diagnose`. I just came across the same issue and it turned out that I had no php-curl installed, which caused the very slow downloads.

Once installed it works like a charm!